# Open workbook, exit sub on failure / abort

Tags: vba, excel, io

I'm trying to open a woorkbook in the background in a macro. When the user exits the open file dialog, I want the program to quit, of course.

But every attempt of doing so failed...

```
' Get the file to open
tempFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
```

What I tried so far:

```
' Catch abort of the open file dialog
If IsEmpty(tempFile) Then
    End
End If
' Catch abort of the open file dialog
If IsEmpty(tempFile) Or Not tempFile Then
    End
End If
' Catch abort of the open file dialog
If IsEmpty(tempFile) Or Not CBool(tempFile) Then
    End
End If
' Catch abort of the open file dialog
If IsEmpty(tempFile) Or tempFile Like "false" Then
    End
End If
```

No matter what, I always get a "Type mismatch" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dim tempFile
tempFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
if tempFile = False then
   'user cancelled the dialog. exit the code
else
   msgbox "User wants to open the file at : " & tempFile
end if
```

Comment: As an addition, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209892(v=office.12).aspx. According to the article, the return type is variant.

Answer (score -2):

Also, be careful because if you do

```
dim tempFile as String
```

...which is probably the correct thing to do, then you have to do the check like this:

```
If tempFile = "False" Then
```

which goes against the grain, but works.

Comment: -1 No, you don't have to. You can, but don't have to. Convince yourself: `Dim s As String: s = "False": Debug.Print s = False`, note `False` not between quotes. And `dim tempFile as String` is not "probably the correct thing to do". `GetOpenFilename` returns a `Variant`. You can coerce it to a string if you want, which is fine, but that doesn't make it probably more correct.